# Using a PHP 'template' for html pages

Tags: php, html, templates

I'm a CS student doing a project, so its really not THAT important. I choose to use php/html as my platform. Anyway, my question is about putting the common html code into a php file, then calling functions from the file to output the html. Is this common practice? This is what I'm doing and it seems to be working OK. My goal (like everyone) is to only have to update one file and have the changes cascade through my website. I'm just curious what the industry standard way of doing this is, and if there are other good ways to do it. Here's a pseudocode example of what I got going now:

```
<?php

class template
{

function sideBar(){ echo <div>..sidebar stuff that is consistent on all pages..</div>

function head(){ echo css import stuff}

function scripts(){echo <script>javascript stuff</script>} //this one didnt work fyi

}


?>
```

and then in the html I do something like this:

```
<?php $template=new template; ?>


<html>
   <head> <?php $template->head(); ?> </head>

<body>
   <?php 
    $template->sidebar(); 

    $template->scripts();
   ?>



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You might want to look in to a template engine, I myself use [TemplatePower](http://templatepower.codocad.com/) for years now. It gives you a good idea how to split up the both.

Comment: If it fit your needs why wouldn't you use it? Most people use a framework(Symfony, CI, Zend, ...). You could also use a template engine like PHPCake or Smarty.

Comment: I will recommended you to use MVC to separate data, logic and views.

Comment: I will have to check out those on the next project. Wouldn't both of these files fall under the views category?

Comment: Check Laravel 4, it's an awesome and properly documented framework with a large active community. Don't reinvent the wheel! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are learning and even tried to create your own template. I think all of good programmers at some poin was writing spaghetti code, then found out `includes` to include some part of page (like having the file for header, footer and even menu.

Then we started to create simple templates - like whole `.html` file with placeholders {{headScript}}, {{PageBody}} and `str_replace` them. So logic is not contained withing html. (1st mvc?)

Next progress was to create a class that we could easly add dynamic scripts, or set current menu item.

For me who started my ,,war'' with programming from structural languages evolution was like the one mentioned above.

When you already had some ways of making that - you found out that others have done quite the same as you

- Zend have its views with some php code to make it dynamic or use `if`'s and `while`'s.
- Smarty is template library - with its own code instead of php (quite php alike, but ppl tend not to be so afraid of that code).
- MANY OTHERS - there is MANY other library or MVC Frameworks that found ways of splitting actual code from the html part.

And as others in comments stated - dont reinvent the wheel - i would suggest you two things

- One is that you continue writing your own code (as you will learn great deal from that)
- If you only need templates - use Smarty - its easy and used only as template framework.

The choice is yours, try learning, look how others are doing it and ,,invent'' your own code. It dont need to be as powerful as Smarty is (it have several years of development already - you are just starting). But this will be your code for CS.